# Does bash have a return code for assignment?

Tags: bash, return-value

I am a bit confused about whether assignments change `$?`

What I have tried so far :

```
$ curl --fail http://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/brms/6.2.0/en/source/MD5
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
$ #I have verified that $? should be 22 at this point
$ var=romeo # Does this change $?
$ echo $? # I expected this to return 22 , but I got zero below
0
```

Please shed some light on this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
   ?      Expands to the exit status of the most recently  executed  fore‐
          ground pipeline.
```

So the assignment changes it. Anything you do, changes it.

```
$ ls alsdaskkad
ls: cannot access alsdaskkad: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
$ echo $?
0
$ echo 1
1
$ echo $?
0
```

And so on.

As [123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) says:

> Even echoing the return changes the return!

Comment: As an aside, `(exit XX)` is an effective way to set `$?` to an arbitrary value.

Comment: Even echoing the return changes the return!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams beautiful! I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's a good way to close your terminal.

Comment: @123: The parens open a subshell.

Comment: @fedorqui : Thankyou and appreciate the time

Comment: Note that "most recently executed foreground pipeline" can include the last command substitution executed in the right-hand side of an assignment, so `foo="$(echo bar; exit 10) $(echo baz; exit 3)"` would leave `$?` set to 3. The assignment statement itself doesn't have an exit status, but can *clear* the value of `$?` if no other statement sets it. I'm not really sure how explain it other than as a special case.