# why in shell script, $? can't echo twice?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have two simple scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "this script return sth"

exit 105
```

and:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "this script will print last script return"

echo "first run a script"
./this_script_return_sth.sh

echo "previous script return value: $?"
echo $?
```

the run result is:

```
this script will print last script return
first run a script
this script return sth
previous script return value: 105
0
```

anything I did wrong? does it means that if I want to use it, it better to first store it to some variable?

Comment: That's because `echo` returns a result too.

Comment: 'cause `$?` is the status of the _last_ executed program or statement. Hint: `echo` is a program as well.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, oops....many thanks!!!

Comment: You can just save it in a variable for later use (`myExitCode=$?` and `echo exit code is $myExitCode`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does bash have a return code for assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046201/does-bash-have-a-return-code-for-assignment)

Comment: What do you mean by `$? can't echo twice?` Kindly search the forum thoroughly before posting questions.  I have asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046201/does-bash-have-a-return-code-for-assignment) before. Hence voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`$?` expands to the last statement's return code. So, the zero says the *last* `echo` statement (i.e. `echo "previous script return value: $?"`) was sucessful.

From [bash manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)

> ?
>   ($?) Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

If you need the value in multiple places, then you can always store in a variable:

```
./this_script_return_sth.sh
rc=$?

echo "previous script return value: $rc"
echo $rc
```

Answer (score 1):

`$?` always returns the status code for the last executed shell command.

In your case, the last line of your script:

```
echo $?
```

prints the return code for the last executed command which is:

```
echo "previous script return value: $?"
```

And not the script.

Answer (score 0):

$? return the exit status of the last command executed.

Every command returns an exit status (sometimes referred to as a return status or exit code). A successful command returns a 0, while an unsuccessful one returns a non-zero value that usually can be interpreted as an error code.

In your first script, you are sending 105 as exit code, so it printed :

```
previous script return value: 105
```

And next line, `echo $?` returned `0` for successful execution of last command.

Your scripts are working as expected.

For more details, refer [Exit status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)